# How to tell which kubernetes service a cluster is using programmatically?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to tell programmatically (using `kubectl`) whether the k8s server you're talking to is running on docker-desktop, k3s, eks, gke etc.?

I am writing a small CLI tool to diagnose issues on our various clusters, but there are some differences between our k3s install and our eks install. Right now the user has to explicitly declare which kubernetes service they are using, but I'd prefer to deduce it automatically and make the tool more 'universal".

Comment: If you use kubectl to describe a node, there should be clues in the System Info and labels portions of the results. But, I think that every deployment would have unique info in those sections, so you'd probably have to log into each environment, describe a node, then write some custom detector for nodes of that specific architecture. But, even then, ymmv. For example, my K3D cluster on my laptop gives me no evidence that it's running in K3D; it seems to report itself as being K3S, which is only partially correct.

Comment: One solution would be to add explicit metadata to each of your clusters indicating which deployment style they use (e.g., via a specific configmap, or by setting labels on the nodes, etc).

Comment: Presumably, an additional requirement is that you don't want to mutate the cluster (e.g. create a Pod) to gain the info either. Could you infer the cloud-platform from the control plane's address `kubectl cluster-info` (unfortunately this command doesn't support structured `--output`)? Additionally, Cloud Platforms provide platform-specific auth so you may be able to infer the platform from the `user` associated with the `cluster` in the `context`. Since this info is static by cluster, once determined, you may want to persist the result.